# Symfony2 and php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to clear the production cache on my Symfony2 project, but I am always getting the same error message:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                        
  Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: header.                             
            Load paths:                                                                 
              /home/milos/workspace/mdpi.com                                            
              /home/milos/workspace/mdpi.com/src/MDPI/MainBundle/Resources/public/scss  
      on line 1 of /tmp/assetic_sasse9Sy3m                                              
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is a permissons problem?

I use to edit my symfony project with an user, but its runs with other, usually www-data (apache user) and its gave to my a lot of problems clearing caches and logs directories.

Try to execute symfony console with www-data user

```
su www-data -c "php app/console cache:clear --env=prod"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like compass error. Browse all *.scss, *.sass files. At the top should import "header", which not exist.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. The same project works well in another computer.